# Socket receiving incomplete data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a p2p network and my socket sends are either sending incomplete data or are breaking before they send the complete data. I'm not exactly sure which is happening or if something else is wrong here. Below is my sending code where I loop and send till the entire msg is sent. I notice that in my listener code further below, my json_loads is throwing exceptions and when I print out the buffer it looks like some bytes are missing from the sends since the dictionaries im sending are incomplete. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Anybody have any idea?

```
def unicast(self, msg, recipient_node):
        #print('UNICAST HERE')
        msg = json.dumps(msg)
        msg_len = len(msg) # add the msg length header with the delimiter here
        msg = f'{msg_len}--->{msg}'
        byte_msg = bytes(msg, 'utf-8')
        unicast_len = len(byte_msg)
        total_sent = 0
        with self.socket_lock:
            try:
                while total_sent < unicast_len:
                    #time.sleep(0.01) # necessary for GIL issues (connection reset by peer)
                    sent = recipient_node['socket'].send(byte_msg[total_sent:])
                    if sent == 0: # disconnected?
                        print('HERE BOIS')
                        break
                    total_sent += sent
            except Exception as e:
                print('HERE BOIS #2')
                pass # disconnected socket or some error that will be handled by listener
```

Here is my listener code where I have a buffer that I believe will parse complete json strings once they've been received accordingly.

```
msg_length = None
        buffer = ''
        while inputs:
            #print(socket_to_identifier)
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
            for s in readable:
                if s is server_socket:
                    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
                    self.sockets_listening += 1
                    client_socket.setblocking(0)
                    inputs.append(client_socket)
                    message_queues[client_socket] = queue.Queue()
                else:
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    if data:
                        #print('NEW RECEIVE HERE') 
                        message_queues[s].put(data)
                        if s not in outputs:
                            outputs.append(s)
                        decoded_recv = data.decode('utf-8')
                        buffer += decoded_recv
                        while True:
                            if msg_length is None:
                                if '--->' not in buffer:
                                    break
                                length_str, ignored, buffer = buffer.partition('--->')
                                msg_length = int(length_str)
                            if len(buffer) < msg_length:
                                break
                            msg = buffer[:msg_length]
                            buffer = buffer[msg_length:]
                            msg_length = None
                            #print(msg)
                            msg = json.loads(msg)
                            if 'node_identifier' in msg: # this is the on connect msg sent
                                socket_to_identifier[s] = msg['node_identifier']
                                break
                            #print(msg)
                            #b_del_thread = Thread(target=self.basic_deliver, args=(msg,))
                            #b_del_thread.start()
                            self.basic_deliver(msg)
                    else:
                        self.handle_disconnect(socket_to_identifier.get(s, None))
                        print('disconnected boys')
                        if s in outputs:
                            outputs.remove(s)
                        inputs.remove(s)
                        s.close()
                        del message_queues[s]
                        
            for s in exceptional:
                self.handle_disconnect(socket_to_identifier.get(s, None))
                inputs.remove(s)
                if s in outputs:
                    outputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
                del message_queues[s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I figured it out. Since I'm using select as my non blocking listener, it is basically one dedicated piece of code to handle EVERY socket connection and so recvs need not be from one node. Instead of on buffer string, I now use a buffer map that maps a client socket to its own buffer so that it doesn't intermix messages from different sockets.